# Where is the second power core?

Tags: horizon-zero-dawn

I know where the ultraweave armor is, and I know that one of the power cores is in the beginning, but where is the other one?

Answer (score 3):

There is more than 2 power cores to collect. From memory there is actually 5. Since this is an end game armour, some are only available in end game locations.

- **Power Cell #1** – The Underground Facility You Fell into as a Child
- **Power Cell #2** – Found in All-Mother Mountain during The Proving Quest
- **Power Cell #3** – Found at the Grave-Hoard during the Grave-Hoard Quest
- **Power Cell #4** – Found at the tip of Faro Skyscraper during the Maker’s End Quest
- **Power Cell #5** – Found inside a Secret Purple Area during The Mountain that Fell Quest